# Calender invite for icalender in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js and was wondering what should be used to create the calender invite object for icalender.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any own research on this matter?

Comment: Can you provide us with more info.? Have you done any research about it already?